# Converting an input string to a numpy slice

Tags: python, numpy

I am taking a `numpy` slice as an input and wish to know what `numpy` converts that into.

For example, if the user input string is `user_input = '[1:10, 2:20:2]'`, and I have an array `arr`, I could use `eval('arr' + user_input)` to get the resulting slice out of the array.

But what I'm looking for instead is something closer to `slice(1,10,1), slice(2,20,2)` or whatever numpy converts that into before doing the actual indexing.

Can this be accessed in anyway?

How do you get the intermediate step of the numpy slice interpretation, but not the actual output array? Or where can I look up how numpy interprets its indexing?

Comment: The interpreter translates that string into a call to `.__getitem__` method. passing in a tuple of `slice` objects. The array version is compiled, but the `index_tricks` module has some interesting uses of this idea. numpy/index_tricks.py

Comment: Is this a question about *parsing* user input?

Comment: Where is this string coming from? Are you reading it from stdin, or is it coming in as a function argument?

Answer (score 1):

To turn a user input string into a slice, you can parse the string and pass it to slice like:

#### Code:

```
def slice_from_string(slice_string):
    slices = slice_string.split(',')
    if len(slices) > 1:
        return [slice_from_string(s.strip()) for s in slices]
    return slice(*[int(x) for x in slice_string.split(':')])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.arange(100)
print(nums[slice_from_string('3:7')])
print(nums[slice_from_string('2:20:2')])

nums = np.mgrid[1:10, 1:10][0]
print(nums)
print(nums[slice_from_string('3:7, 1:3')])
```

#### Test Results:

```
[3 4 5 6]

[ 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18]

[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
 [6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]
 [8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]]

[[4 4]
 [5 5]
 [6 6]
 [7 7]]
```

Comment: Try it on `user_input = '[1:10, 2:20:2]'`

Answer (score 0):

If I define a dummy class

```
class Foo():
    def __getitem__(self, atuple):
        #print(atuple)
        return atuple
```

Then I can use `eval` to an expression into a tuple with slices:

```
In [140]: x=eval('f[0:2, 1:10:2,[1,2,2],4]')
In [141]: x
Out[141]: (slice(0, 2, None), slice(1, 10, 2), [1, 2, 2], 4)

In [142]: astr = '[0:2, 1:10:2,[1,2,2],4]'
In [143]: eval('f{}'.format(astr))
Out[143]: (slice(0, 2, None), slice(1, 10, 2), [1, 2, 2], 4)
```

This tuple can be used to index via:

```
In [144]: arr = np.arange(3*10*3*5).reshape(3,10,3,5)
In [145]: arr[x]
Out[145]: 
array([[[ 24,  29,  29],
        [ 54,  59,  59],
        [ 84,  89,  89],
        [114, 119, 119],
        [144, 149, 149]],

       [[174, 179, 179],
        [204, 209, 209],
        [234, 239, 239],
        [264, 269, 269],
        [294, 299, 299]]])
```

The `ast` module has a safer `ast.literal_eval`, but it doesn't handle indexing.

As I commented, `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` has some interesting examples of using the class syntax as an alternative to function syntax.  `np.r_`, `np.ogrid`,and `np.s_` are the most useful examples:

```
In [150]: np.s_[0:2, 1:10:2,[1,2,2],4]
Out[150]: (slice(0, 2, None), slice(1, 10, 2), [1, 2, 2], 4)
```

In fact I don't need to define that `Foo` class; I can use `np.s_` instead

```
In [151]: eval('np.s_{}'.format(astr))
Out[151]: (slice(0, 2, None), slice(1, 10, 2), [1, 2, 2], 4)
```

`arr[x]` is translated into `arr.__getitem__(x)`.  But explaining exactly what goes on inside that compiled array `__getitem__` is beyond my expertise.